# How can I make a drawing canvas work in a Bootstrap layout?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

I'm currently having a problem with getting a basic drawing canvas to work in a Bootstrap layout. It works when used outside of a Bootstrap column, but when used inside it doesn't seem to work (by this I mean it's not taking input/showing the drawing).

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="content-box text-center">
            <h1 id="upd-timer">--</h1> seconds
        </div>
        <div class="content-box">
            <b>Scoreboard</b><hr>
            <div id="upd-scoreboard"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content-box">
            <b>Drawing Board</b><hr>
            <canvas id='draw-board' height='500' width='500'></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="content-box">
            <b>Game Chat</b><hr>
            <div class="game-chat game-chat-lobby" id="upd-game-chat"></div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="game-chat-form">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS code, for the drawing canvas:

```
var clickX = new Array ();
var clickY = new Array ();
var clickDrag = new Array ();

var paint;

function createDrawBoard ()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById  ('draw-board');
    context = canvas.getContext  ('2d');

    $ ('#draw-board').mousedown (function (e)
    {
        var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        paint = true;
        addClick (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
        redraw ();
    });

    $ ('#draw-board').mousemove (function (e)
    {
        if  (paint)
        {
            addClick (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
            redraw ();
        }
    });

    $ ('#draw-board').mouseup  (function (e)
    {
        paint = false;
    });

    $ ('#draw-board').mouseleave  (function (e)
    {
        paint = false;
    });
}

function addClick (x, y, dragging)
{
    clickX.push (x);
    clickY.push (y);
    clickDrag.push (dragging);
}

function redraw ()
{
    context.clearRect (0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

    context.strokeStyle = '#df4b26';
    context.lineJoin = 'round';
    context.lineWidth = 5;

    for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++)
    {   
        context.beginPath ();

        if (clickDrag[i] && i)
        {
            context.moveTo (clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
        }
        else
        {
            context.moveTo (clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
        }

        context.lineTo (clickX[i], clickY[i]);
        context.closePath ();
        context.stroke ();
    }
}
```

Help with this would be greatly appreciated! Unsure how to go about fixing this.